# return Task.ContinueWith<TResult>() without knowing TResult

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

How do I create and return a continuation Task using reflection or by any other means if I only have access the Task?

I need a way to let an exception in the continuation travel back to the original caller. As far as I know this can only be done by returning the continuation task instead of the original task. The problem comes in that I don't know the result type of the Task so can't create a proper continuation Task.

Edit:
I cannot change signature types. I have many interfaces that return Task< TResult > objects and can't expect the client to get Task< Object > results. These interfaces are WCF contracts. I want to do some extra validation logic after the "core" logic method is done and throw an exception if needed. This exception must travel back to client but it does not travel back currently because I'm not returning the continuation task yet. Also I don't know the type beforehand because I'm applying a postsharp aspect and using the OnExit() override, this gives me access to a return value that I know is a Task but it can be any number of Task objects of which TResult is only known at runtime.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace TaskContinueWith
    {
        internal class Program
        {
            private static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    Task<string> myTask = Interceptor();
                    myTask.Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            private static Task<string> Interceptor()
            {
                Task<string> task = CoreLogic(); //Ignore


                Task unknownReturnType = task; //This is what I have access to. A Task object which can be one of numerous Task<TResult> types only known at runtime.

                Task continuation = unknownReturnType.ContinueWith(
                    t =>
                        {
                         if(someCondition)
                         {
                             throw new Exception("Error");
                         }

                         return t.Result; //This obviously does not work since we don't know the result. 
                    });

                return continuation;
            }


            private static async Task<string> CoreLogic()
            {
                return "test";
            }
        }
    }
```

Another way to express the problem.

1. I can only change what is inside DoExtraValidation().
2. I cannot change the signature of DoExtraValidation() to use generics.

**How do I change DoExtraValidation to make it work for any Task< TResult > return type?**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskContinueWith
{
    interface IServiceContract
    {
        Task<string> DoWork();
    }

    public class Servce : IServiceContract
    {
        public Task<string> DoWork()
        {
            var task = Task.FromResult("Hello");
            return  (Task<string>) DoExtraValidation(task);
        }

        private static Task DoExtraValidation(Task task)
        {
            Task returnTask = null;
            if (task.GetType() == typeof(Task<string>))
            {
                var knownType = task as Task<string>;
                returnTask = task.ContinueWith(
                    t =>
                    {
                        if(new Random().Next(100) > 50)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Error");
                        }
                        return knownType.Result;

                    });
            }
            return returnTask;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                IServiceContract myService = new Servce();
                Task<string> myTask = myService.DoWork();
                myTask.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order for your example to work, the unknownReturnType Task must be a `Task<string>` since that is what your `Interceptor()` method returns.  Is it always a `Task<string>`?  If so, then a cast will work.  If not, then you could return Task<object> and then the client code would need to figure out (somehow) what it was getting back.  But my question would be--why don't you know the type that is being returned?  It would be better to give a better description of what you're trying to do--there might be better solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a case for `dynamic`. I'll try to use as little `dynamic` as possible. First we define a strongly-typed helper:

```
static Task<TResult> SetContinuation<TResult>(Task<TResult> task)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(
        t =>
            {
             if(someCondition)
             {
                 throw new Exception("Error");
             }

             return t.Result;
        });
}
```

This function obviously works, but it requires `TResult` to be known. `dynamic`can fill it in:

```
Task continuation = SetContinuation((dynamic)unknownReturnType);
```

I just tested that the binding works at runtime. Alternatively you can use reflection instead to invoke the helper (use `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` and others).

Comment: I've made some changes but it seems to throw the following. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: An object reference is re quired for the non-static field, method, or property 'TaskContinueWith.Program.S etContinuation<TResult>(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>)' at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object ) at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site

Comment: I made the method static to fix the error. Answering your other comment: The key is the `dynamic` which internally uses reflection indeed! It will fill out the type parameter at runtime. Try it.

Comment: Yes it works at last :) Question. Which would be fastest. 1. Call the SetContinuation using dynamic. or 2. Use a compileTimeGenerated MethodInfo object and call invoke? I think 2 should be faster no? Reason I ask is I can use Resharper's compileTime magic to generate a generic method for me so it saves some time on runtime.

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "compileTimeGenerated MethodInfo". Anyway, dynamic will be faster because it IL-emits a method at runtime that specializes on the concrete type given to it. This is very fast if you have very few different types at runtime. (You could hand-build this if you wanted but the DLR automates it).

Comment: Remember that each different task subtype will need a different `MethodInfo`.

Comment: Postsharp allows me to do MethodInfo methodTocall = continuationMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { genericType }); at compileTime. This methodTocall is then available to me at runtime. So all the reflection is done at compiletime instead of at runtime. But as you say I'm unsure if the invoke will be as fast as the dynamic call to the method.

Comment: Can you post the code that R# suggests? I'm curious. Anyway, if the perf is important to you here you can try this: keep a static Dictionary<Type, Func<Task, Task>> where you create a dynamically compiled "invoker" for SetContinuation for each subtype of Task that you see at runtime. That would be a cache for fast invoking delegates. But that's a lot of work...

Comment: Sorry I was talking about Postsharp... lol I'm very tired. Has nothing todo with Resharper.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33297/discussion-between-tersius-and-usr)

Answer (score 1):

You could use generics (Interceptor is here an extension method):

```
public static class ProjectExtensions
{
    public static Task<T> Interceptor<T>(this Task<T> task)
    {
        Task<T> continuation = task.ContinueWith<T>(t =>
            {
            if(someCondition)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error");
            }
            return t.Result;
        });
        return continuation;
    }
}
```

This way a call can be of any type:

```
var t1 = new Task<string>(() => /* return string */).Interceptor();
var t2 = new Task<int>(() => /* return int */).Interceptor();
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I moved it. Anyway. I can't see how this will work since it requires some type info to be passed to the extension method. I do not have type info like that. I can only use reflection. How would I invoke this method using reflection to allow type info to go through?

Comment: @Tersius, this solution is correct for the 2nd example that you gave (since in that example at the time of calling DoValidation, it is known that you are dealing with a Task<string>).  If you want a better example, show us a concise but real example showing where the method DoExtraValidation doesn't know the type information.